# Getting unknown function mean() in a forvalues loop

Tags: stata

Getting unknown function `mean` for this. Can't use `egen` because it has to be calculated for each value. A little confused.

```
edu_mov_avg=.
forvalues current_year =  2/133 {
    local current_mean = mean(higra) if longitbirthqtr >= current_year - 2  & longitbirthqtr >= current_year + 2
    replace edu_mov_avg = current_mean if longitbirthqtr = 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a long way from working. This should be closer.

```
gen edu_mov_avg = .
qui forvalues current_qtr =  2/133 {
    su higra if inrange(longitbirthqtr, `current_qtr' - 2, `current_qtr' + 2), meanonly  
    replace edu_mov_avg = r(mean) if longitbirthqtr == `current_qtr' 
}
```

1. You need to use a command `generate` to produce a new variable.
2. You need to reference local macro values with quotation marks.
3. `egen` has its own `mean()` function, but it produces a variable, whereas you need a constant here. Using `summarize, meanonly` is the most efficient method. There is in Stata no `mean()` function that can be applied anywhere. Once you use `summarize`, there is no need to use a local macro to hold its results. Here `r(mean)` can be used directly.
4. You have `>=` twice, but presumably don't mean that. Using `inrange()` is not essential in writing your condition, but gives shorter code.
5. You can't use `if` qualifiers to qualify assignment of `local` macros in the way you did. They make no sense to Stata, as such macros are constants.
6. `longitbirthqtr` looks like a quarterly date. Hence I didn't use the name `current_year`.

With a window this short, there is an alternative using time series operators

```
tsset current_qtr 
gen edu_mov_avg = (L2.higra + L1.higra + higra + F1.higra + F2.higra) / 5
```

That is not exactly equivalent as missings will be returned for the first two observations and the last two.

Your code may need further work if your data are panel data. But the time series operators approach remains easy so long as you declare the panel identifier, e.g.

```
tsset panelid current_qtr
```

after which the `generate` call is the same as above.

All that said, `rolling` offers a framework for such calculations.