# How to take maximum of rolling window without SSC packages

Tags: stata

How can I create a variable in Stata that contains the maximum of a dynamic rolling window applied to another variable? The rolling window must be able to change iteratively within a loop.

`max(numvar, L1.numvar, L2.numvar)` will give me what I want for a single window size, but how can I change the window size iteratively within the loop?

My current code for calculating the rolling sum (credit to @Nick Cox for the algorithm):

```
generate var1lagged = 0

forval k = -2(1)2 {
    if `k' < 0 {
        local k1 = -(`k')
        replace var1lagged = var1lagged + L`k1'.var1
}
    else replace var1lagged = var1lagged + F`k'.var1
}
```

How would I achieve the same sort of flexibility but with the maximum, minimum, or average of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case suppose `K` at least 1 is given as the number of lags in the window

```
local arg L1.numvar

forval k = 2/`K' { 
      local arg `arg', L`k'.numvar 
}

gen wanted = max(`arg')
```

If the window includes the present value, that is just a twist

```
local arg numvar 

forval k = 1/`K' {
    local arg `arg', L`k'.numvar 
} 

gen wanted = max(`arg')
```

More generally, `numvar` would not be a specific variable name, but would be a local macro including such a name.

EDIT 1

This returns missing as a result only if all arguments are missing. If you wanted to insist on missing as a result if any argument is missing, then go

```
gen wanted = cond(missing(`arg'), ., max(`arg'))
```

EDIT 2

Check out `rolling` more generally. Otherwise for a rolling mean you calculate directly you need to work out (1) the sum as in the question (2) the number of non-missing values.

The working context of the OP evidently rules out installing community-contributed commands; otherwise I would recommend `rangestat` and `rangerun` (SSC). Note that many community-contributed commands have been published via the *Stata Journal*, GitHub or user sites.

Comment: So it appears that Stata is ignoring the missing values in the calculation, is there a way to make it so that if I try to take the max of three numbers and two of them are missing (like for the very first row) the result will be `.`?

Comment: Yes; that's utterly standard in Stata. Asked to find the maximum of 1, 2, 42, 666 and . (missing) Stata returns 666, not missing as "don't know". See EDIT.

Comment: You mention in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971326/getting-unknown-function-mean-in-a-forvalues-loop) that there is no such thing as a function ```mean()``` anywhere in Stata. How can I use the above algorithm to get the mean instead of the max? I would have thought that it would be really easy to just put in a ```mean()``` instead of the ```max()``` found above, but it gives the error ```unknown function mean()```.

Comment: The moving average function you mentioned in another post (I cannot recall right now) doesn't put ```.``` when data is missing, which keeps me from using it.

Comment: What I said is that there is no `mean()` function that can be applied just anywhere, not that there is no such function anywhere in the machinery, as there is such a function within `egen` (and that's overloading the term "function"). (and one in Mata).

Comment: I am curious why Stata would choose to have a ```max()``` function that can be applied to a macro while not including a ```mean()``` function. They seem to be in the same toolbox.

Comment: The original design focused on statistics for variables, not within observations. I can’t speak for the original designers.